# Evenly spaced table-cells

Tags: org-mode, org-table, align

I would like to change the following spacing behavior so that ideally all begin and end of columns are lined up (evenly spaced).

All rows should stretch as much as the largest of them.

[image: Current table space-rendering]

Comment: I suspect this or a similar question might already have been asked. try searching for **[align]** (i.e., tag `align`).

Comment: @Drew I found Chinese, Arabic et al problems which were solved through the use of monospaced fonts. But, my problem seems rather other. I use     

(set-face-attribute 'fixed-pitch nil :font "Fira Code Retina" :height efs/default-font-size)

Comment: It would be really nice if you entered the table as text in your question, so that we could cut-and-paste it into our own emacs and experiment. Images are useless for that. Thanks for not using images next time :-)

Comment: Thanks for searching for a duplicate! That helps (everyone) a lot.

Comment: There is a way to set the maximum width of a column using a `<N>` cookie, but AFAIK no way to fix the width (i.e. set both the minimum and the maximum).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a mono-space font, the columns should align.  There is no clear way to align columns in emacs using a variable-spaced font.